# Find a square root of a Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, hermitian-matrices

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1+j  \\1-j  & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. Find $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and a $B\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $A=BB^*.$

I have tried to write down three equations using elements of $B$ and one equation using the fact that determinant of $A$ is zero. But it didn't help.

Any smarter way to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that $A$ is a Hermitian matrix so the Spectral Theorem applies to it.

Comment: @then $B$ will be equal to $UD$, where $U$ is unitary and $D=\mathrm{diag}\{\sqrt3,0\}$, it means I need to find that particular $U$ that diagonalize $A$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Since $A$ has rank one the matrix $B$ is a column. It is pretty obvious (without calculations) what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $u$ is a unit-vector spanning the image of $A$, then we can take $B = \alpha u$ for some scalar $\alpha > 0$.

We then have
$$
A = BB^* = \alpha^2 uu^*.
$$
If we take $M = \alpha \,uu^*$, then we find that 
$$
M^2 = (\alpha uu^*)(\alpha uu^*) = \alpha^2 u(u^*u)u = \alpha^2 uu^* = A.
$$
Because $M$ is positive definite, we conclude that $M = A^{1/2}$.